# How to use OpenLDAP for Oracle database user authentication

Tags: oracle, openldap

In our enterprise, we have a large number of Oracle databases and (obviously) large number of users with access to different databases. We would like to ease the procedure to create/drop/modify users on an enterprise level. A LDAP solution comes to mind but the solutions from Oracle Corp are too expensive. Needless to say, my mgmt asked me to research and come up with an alternative. I read about OpenLDAP. My questions:

1. How do I setup OpenLDAP for oracle user security authentication ?
2. Can I use OpenLDAP as a standalone or does it have to be integrated with any Oracle product like OID, OVD, ODSEE etc?
3. Are there are any certified install procedures for setting up OpenLDAP w/ Oracle database?

I didn't find anything on the internet for setting up OpenLDAP. Any help/pointer would be appreciated. The goal is to avoid any products from Oracle Corp purely for cost reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Permitted Features, Options, and Management Packs by Oracle Database Offering](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBLIC/Licensing-Information.htm#DBLIC-GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87)

> Enterprise User Security is a feature for directory-based management
>   of database users. **It requires a corresponding Oracle Identity
>   Management Directory Services Plus to be licensed.**

[Enterprise User Security: The Big Picture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBIMI/introducing-enterprise-user-security.htm#DBIMI203)

> Enterprise User Security requires Oracle Internet Directory 10g
>   (9.0.4) or higher. Other LDAP-compliant directory services are
>   supported by using Oracle Internet Directory Integration Platform to
>   synchronize them with Oracle Internet Directory. Another directory
>   services product, Oracle Virtual Directory, provides a single, dynamic
>   access point to multiple data sources through LDAP or XML protocols.
>   Oracle Virtual Directory can provide multiple application-specific
>   views of identity data stored in, for example, Oracle Internet
>   Directory, Microsoft Active Directory and Sun Java Systems Directory
>   instances, and can also be used to secure data access to the
>   application-specific sources and enhance high-availability to existing
>   data-sources.

1. Through Oracle Virtual Directory or Oracle Unified Directory.
2. See above. Technically it should be possible to use as standalone, but not supported at all.
3. None for direct connection. See above.